# Добавление Foreign key с условием

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, веб-программирование, postgresql

У меня есть 3 таблицы:
**Inventory1** : *id | item*
**Inventory2** : *id | item*
**Warehouse** : _id | inventory_id | type_
Inventory1 и Inventory2 это таблицы, которые похожи, но содержат информацию для разных блоков сайта. В свою очередь Warehouse содержит последовательность записей Inventory при этом важна последовательность (например сначала идет строка из Inventory1-Inventory1-Inventory2-Inventory1 и т.д.) для определения к какой из двух таблиц относится запись в Warehouse используется поле **type**.
**Основной вопрос:** можно ли настроить внешний ключ (с ON DELETE CASCADE возможно с условием типа WHERE type = 1/0 ?) таким образом, чтобы например удалении строки из Inventory1 приводило к удалению записи в Warehouse именно с inventory_id = Inventory1.id?
Возможно есть вариант более правильной архитектуры таблиц для данной задачи?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется в вашем случае лучше использовать триггерную функцию.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.delete_inventory()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$DECLARE
pid integer;

BEGIN
pid = NEW.id;
IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
DELETE FROM Warehouse where id = pid
RETURN OLD;

END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.delete_inventory()
OWNER TO postgres;
```